# my Hyundai vibrates at RPM 3K

Tags: noise, hyundai, vibration, rpm, i30-wagon

i have Hyundai i30 2008, and the car vibrate at RPM 3k. if i go before or after the 3k, the problem disappear. the vibration happens when gear on or in neutral. the car has automatic transmission and the fuel is gasoline. when the gear is on, and RPM at 3k, the car vibrate and i can hear continuous loud sound (in neutral the sound is not loud).

Comment: Interesting question. Any ideas on possible causes?